# How to set parameter for flash in web application?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, argument-passing

What's the best way to pass a predefined argument to **flash**?

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as name-value pairs in the SWF's URL.

```
"mymovie.swf?defColor=blue&stage=3"
```

and read it from the [loaderInfo.parameters](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#parameters) property of the `root` movie clip - the one with the document class.

```
var params:Object = root.loaderInfo.parameters;
//or this.loaderInfo.parameters if you're calling from the document class.
trace(params.defColor); // dot sytax and
trace(params["stage"]); // []  syntax works.
```

Comment: @wamp `root` is `_root` in AS2, but that's a little different from the AS3 root concept I believe. I am not sure if it has `loaderInfo` property either.

Comment: I just verified that it's not available in `as2`