# How to pass parameters to actionscript 2 in flash?

Tags: flash, parameter-passing

I read though [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234533/how-to-set-parameter-for-flash-in-web-application/3234586#3234586) for `as3`, which is not working for `as2`.

What's the most compatible way to handle parameters in flash?

Answer (score 0):

There a lot of possibilities to achieve it, the one I prefer is using FlashVars with [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/):

```
<div id="flashcontent">
Your message if JavaScript is not enabled.
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var so = new SWFObject("yourmovie.swf", "yourmovie", "950", "30", "9");
so.addVariable("color", "red");
so.addVariable("speed", "3");
so.write("flashcontent");
</script>
```

Once your movie is loaded, the "color" and "speed" variables will be available from _root:

```
trace(_root.color);
```

To ensure FlashVars are loaded correctly, I use an onEnterFrame function that loops until the external variables are loaded (!= undefined).

Comment: No, it's not but it was merely illustrative, I updated the code with a more cross-browser solution.