# Get output of a website with Flash Action Script 2.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I've downloaded an open source flash application written in **action script 2.0** that I want to complete a little bit. I want to give a new value for one of the variable that a function uses. The new value would be a string that comes from my website's output. Im not really familiar with action script, could you please help me how can I do that?

```
    public static function start(varThatNeedsNewValue:String, options:Object):Void{
      var url="http://mysite.com/flash.php";
      ///////////
      /*Grab the output content of the url
      varThatNeedsNewValue=CONTENT OF OUTPUT*/
      ///////////
      //Then let the original script running on...
    }
```

I tried few methods what I've found here on stackoverflow but none of them was successful, so thats why I ask you guys.

Comment: Is loadVars what you are looking for? http://snipplr.com/view/8878/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to retrieve the innerHTML of a web page.
I'm not sure how to do this in AS2 but you can however just pass any variables you need (maybe even the whole content of the page) via javascript (PHP is server side so that may not work with external things like ) when you embed the flash file... Here is information on how to do that: [How to pass parameters to actionscript 2 in flash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237402/how-to-pass-parameters-to-actionscript-2-in-flash)